# Fix razor WebPages with friendly URL returning 404 error

Tags: iis, razor, http-status-code-404, friendly-url

I have a website written as razor ASP.Net code wit the extension .cshtml. I wrote the site using [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) and the site runs fine when i run it on web martix's "*LocalHost*". The links and all my code work, but as soon as I try to run the website from my IIS server the page links no longer work properly. When I click on a link it returns the 404 error page. If I type in the .cshtml extension the page loads correctly and all is right with the world *except* the file extension. The only page that still works is the index page because it is a default page.

Every place I've checked says that it should run without the extension as a default of asp.net or if it doesn't run as default then use the url re-write plugin.

The Default isn't running and I am unable to use the URL rewrite tool.

**What can I do to get the default to work or is there another way to have the extensions not display *without* using URL re-write**

ps. I know that if I put the files in a folder with the link name and rename them to index.cshtml This will work but I feel it is a very backhanded way of doing it so I would prefer not to do it that way.

pps. before any one suggests a solution for mvc I am explicitly ***NOT USING MVC*** Logic. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try two things:

1. Set the application pool to ASP.NET 4.0. Then restart I IIS.
2. Add  the following key to `<system.webServer>` section of Web.Config:

   `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"   />`

Comment: This worked perfectly ! I used solution 2 thank you.